# Display hebrew language sqlplus

Tags: c#, oledb, sqlplus, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

> I am trying with oracle database to Insert and select Hebrew letters
>   and it not working well.
>
> I tried
>
> ```
> Insert into mytable values ('היי');
> ```
>
> and the result is ??? and not היי
>
> can someone help me with that

Edit:

Now after i ask from DBA for hebrew option i can write in Hebrew from the sqlplus

but now from my project it still write ???

my code is

```
OleDbConnection conn = Connect();
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("Insert into mytable values ('היי')", conn);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and still the result is ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database character set has to support unicode characters in order to be able to store non-ascii characters. This setting is defined by the DBA when creating the database which means your DBA most likely needs to recreate the database from scratch. This is not an easy option if the database is already in use by developers or even worse if this database is in production. The organisations generally take it on as a project.

Comment: thank you i ask from DBA to add the option to enter hebrew now i edit the topic cause i need other help, i can enter hebrew now

Comment: I am not sure if your problem is solved or not. If not, look at the NLS_CHARACTERSET and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET values in the following statement: select * from nls_database_parameters. See if these charactersets will support Hebrew characters or not.